# Lock a registry key programmatically to avoid concurrency issues

Tags: c#, c++, winapi

I'm writing an app that needs to write registry values inside of a key in a particular order, and other applications could be writing to the same key, at the same time.

Is there a way to temporarily lock a registry key for writes, to avoid multiple processes writing to this registry key at the same time, and the values getting messed up / out of order?

e.g. I need to write to `HKCU\Software\Company\Product\` which already contains the values below:

- `Start1` = `"abc"`
- `Start2` = `"def"`
- `Start3` = `"ghi"`

Because the last one is `Start3`, I need to create `Start4`.

The problem is if another process is running at the same time, detects that `Start3` is the last one, and overrides my `Start4` that I just created (because it didn't see it due to concurrency).

> **What would be a good way to prevent that from happening?**

I don't have control over which (or how many) applications are writing to this key, and as such I can't tell them to pause or anything like that...

I'm looking for something like the pseudo-code below:

```
Registry.Lock("HKCU\Software\Company\Product\");
Registry.Write("Start4", "jkl");
Registry.Unlock("HKCU\Software\Company\Product\");
```

Comment: You may want to take a look at `RegOpenKeyTransacted`

Comment: Those keys are oddly specific. Not at all the kind where a random Programm would just waltz in and change a value. So maybe there is a underlying lack of coordination like in this old Blogpost? https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110310-00/?p=11253 | Or maybe what you actually want is a single instance pattern on the writing programm? https://www.meziantou.net/single-instance-of-an-application-in-csharp.htm

Comment: Thank you @Jim, I looked at `RegOpenKeyTransacted` but it doesn't quite do what I need because it still allows other processes to write to the same key... As the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regopenkeytransacteda) says: _When a key is opened using this function, subsequent operations on the key are transacted. If a non-transacted operation is performed on the key before the transaction is committed, the transaction is rolled back_

Comment: Thank you @Christopher, the key I wrote in my question is not exactly the key I'm writing - it's just an example. I know for sure that several other apps write to the key I'm interested in, and it's not a key that my apps creates or owns... It's a key for installing plugins into an app. Creating these values registers a plugin with the app that owns the key... No coordination is possible between the apps because they don't know about each other. It would have to be something that Windows provides

Comment: *the transaction is rolled back* means you will get an error code back, at which point you can check the new state and retry (e.g. you'll see that Start4 already exists for example).

Comment: @rustyx Yeah... That seems to be the only option (requiring lots of retry logic and stuff). I was hoping for a way to lock it the same way we can lock files and databases :(

Comment: What advantage does transacted registry API give you over a global mutex? Your applications would have to agree about using transacted API, couldn't they agree about using a mutex aswell? It would certainly simplify things.

Comment: @zett42 As I said in my question: I do not have control over other applications that write to the same key... In other words: They are not **my** applications... The key I'm writing is a key used by many 3rd party apps in the market

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like I'm going to answer my own question unfortunately.

> #### [Writing and Deleting Registry Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/writing-and-deleting-registry-data)
>
> **It is not possible to lock a registry key during a write operation to**
>   **synchronize access to the data**. However, you can control access to a
>   registry key using security attributes. For more information, see
>   [Registry Key Security and Access Rights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/registry-key-security-and-access-rights).
>
> More than one registry operation can be performed within a single
>   transaction. To associate a registry key with a transaction, an
>   application can use the [RegCreateKeyTransacted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Winreg/nf-winreg-regcreatekeytransacteda) or [RegOpenKeyTransacted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Winreg/nf-winreg-regopenkeytransacteda)
>   function. For more information about transactions, see [Kernel Transaction Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/desktop/Ktm/kernel-transaction-manager-portal).
>
> From: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/writing-and-deleting-registry-data

Comment: Answering your own question is never a bad thing. You were able to help yourself, and by posting the answer you are helping other people in the future.

Comment: And don't forget mark it yourself, so that People who seek help can easily find what they most likely want.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder @DrakeWu-MSFT. At the time I posted the answer, I didn't have enough reputation to mark my own answer as a valid answer... But now I do

Answer (score 1):

You have to use proper synchronization using the [Mutex functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/using-mutex-objects). Registry API, as most Windows API, is not threadsafe.

Comment: Thank you @Michael. Unfortunately I don't have control over which (or how many) applications are writing to this key, so I cannot cooperate with them via Mutex or anything because we don't know about each other...

Comment: @Lindsey1986 _"don't have control over which (or how many) applications are writing to this key"_ -- that's exactly the problem that a global named mutex solves! Your apps only have to agree on the mutex name and don't have to know anything else about each other.

Comment: How exactly are apps he doesn't have control over supposed to agree with each other over a mutex name?

Comment: @ĴošħWilliard OP seems to have enough control to let them agree about using transacted registry API. If so, they could be able to agree about mutex aswell.

Comment: @zett42 I do not have control over other applications that write to the same key... They are 3rd-party applications that I do not know, do not control, and they don't know my app exist. It is impossible to have any kind of cooperation between these apps...